# Calculating sum of BesselJ[n, x]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions, summation

My friend has a sum in his research paper that looks like this

$$
 \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{J_n^2(x)}{n-\kappa}.
 $$

He was able to calculate this sum analytically, by substituting the denominator with an integral. I wonder, is there a way to calculate this in *Mathematica* by adjusting some options in the `Sum[BesselJ[n, x]^2/(n - К), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]`.

Thank you in advance!

**UPD**
People were interested in how to take this sum analytically. So if you substitute

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{J_n^2(x)}{n-\kappa} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n^2(x)(-i)\int_0^\infty e^{-i(\kappa-n)t}\mathrm{d}t =,
$$

where we can now exchange the integration and summation and use $n\to-n$ symmetry

$$
=(-i)\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}t\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}J_n^2(x)\left(e^{-i(\kappa-n)t}+e^{-i(\kappa+n)t}\right)+J_0^2(x)e^{-i\kappa t}\right\}.
$$

Then we take out the $e^{-i\kappa t}$ and get $2\cos{nt}$, so the whole sum becomes

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{J_n^2(x)}{n-\kappa} = (-i)\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}t\left[e^{-i\kappa t}\left\{2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}J_n^2(x)\cos{nt}+J_0^2(x)\right\}\right],
$$

and now can be easily taken

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{J_n^2(x)}{n-\kappa} =(-i)\int_0^\infty e^{-i\kappa t}J_0\left(2x\sin{\left({t\over 2}\right)}\right)\mathrm{d}t.
$$

Now we have a geometrical progression $a_{n+1}=qa_{n}$, where

$$
a_0=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i\kappa t}J_0\left(2x\sin{\left({t\over 2}\right)}\right)\mathrm{d}t,~~\text{and}~~q =e^{-2\pi i \kappa}.
$$

So

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{J_n^2(x)}{n-\kappa} =(-i)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n=i\frac{a_0}{q-1}.
$$
$a_0$ can be found using the integrals shown below on pic, but still *Mathematica* is not helpful to take it.

[image: pics]

Comment: What do you mean by "substituting the denominator with an integral"?  I mean, you can do `Integrate @@ Sum[ ... ]`, but that probably won't be equal to the original expression and in any event Mathematica doesn't evaluate that either.

Comment: I added the brief explanation in the __upd__.

Comment: @HaykHakobyan your link of $a_0$ may be broken. Please check it.

Comment: @tanghe2014 fixed, thnx.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mathematica returns

```
Sum[BesselJ[n, x]^2/(n - k), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

unevaluated.  However, `BesselJ[n, x]^2` and `BesselJ[-n, x]^2` are equal, so the `Sum` can be rewritten as

```
Simplify[-BesselJ[0, x]^2/k + 2 k Sum[BesselJ[n, x]^2/(n^2 - k^2), {n, 1, Infinity}]]
(* -π BesselJ[-k, x] BesselJ[k, x] Csc[k π] *)
```

which is the desired result.  Its plot, here for `k == .5`, is

```
Plot[Evaluate[% /. k -> .5], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, sum}]
```

[image]

The sum converges quite rapidly, at least for `k == .5`.  Define

```
f[nmax_, x_, k_] := Sum[BesselJ[n, x]^2/(n - k), {n, -nmax, nmax}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[nm, x, .5], {nm, 0, 5, 1}]], {x, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, sum}]
```

[image]

The curve for `nm == 3` is essentially identical to that for the symbolic `Sum`.  Convergence probably is not so rapid for larger `k`.

Answer (score 6):

Using Laplace transform:
$$\mathcal{L}_t[J_0(a \sinh (b t))](s)=\frac{I_{\frac{s}{2 b}}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)
   K_{-\frac{s}{2 b}}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{b}$$
where I'm found in this [Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2881248373) on page 276 example 1.

Using identity:

$$a \sin (b t)=-i a \sinh (i b t)$$

all combining together:

```
 (-I)*(BesselI[s/(2 b), a/2] BesselK[-(s/(2 b)), a/2])/b /. a -> -I*2*x /. 
 b -> I/2 /. s -> I*k
```

> -2 BesselI[k, -I x] BesselK[-k, -I x]

```
Sum[BesselJ[n, x]^2/(n - k), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}] == Re[-2 BesselI[k, -I x] BesselK[-k, -I x]]
```

$$\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{J_n(x){}^2}{n-k}=\Re(-2 I_k(-i x) K_{-k}(-i x))$$

**Comment:**

Formula works for:$x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $k=c+\frac{1}{2}$ where $c\in \mathbb{Z}$